# Logstash “elapsed” filter - double "start" event

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

If I define my [elapsed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) filter like so:

```
elapsed {
  start_tag => "task-started"
  end_tag => "task-terminated"
  unique_id_field => "task-id"
  timeout => 1200
  new_event_on_match => true
}
```

What will happen if there are 2 consecutive events with a `start_tag` and the same `task-id`?

I can think of a few possibilities:

- The start time will be reset to the second "start" event time
- The first event will be considered as an error since it did not get an "end" event, so an error event will be issued and then the second event will be handled normally.
- The second "start" event will be ignored

So which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elapsed filter collects all the "start events". If two, or more, "start events" have the same ID, only the first one is recorded, the others are discarded.